# Equally distribute the height of an unknown number of children divs inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say that I have the following (2) divs:

Example #1

```
<div style="height:100px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Example #2

```
<div style="height:400px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

I would like to automatically and equally distribute the height for the child divs without specifically stating the height.

Under normal circumstances, for the first example, I could state a height of 50px (or 50%) for each of the inside divs. And for #2, I could state a height of 100px (or 25%) for each of the inside divs.

The problem is that I will have an unlimited number of parent div heights and an unknown number of children divs within the parents (some may have one child, while others may have 5 or more). So, I need a way to have the children divs automatically distribute the height between each other regardless of how many exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KQZZy/

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $children = $this.children();

    $children.height($this.height() / $children.length - 2);
});
```

Note that the `- 2` is to adjust for the borders I have on the divs and in your case may be unneeded.

Answer (score 4):

Just get the parent's height, divide by the number of child div's and set their heights.

```
var $parent = $('div#parent'),
    $children = $parent.children(),
    child_height = $parent.height() / $children.size();

$children.height(child_height);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to use `display: table;`. Unfortunately, that leaves out Internet Explorer 6 and below. But consider how easy-to-read [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcdJg/) is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="auto-height" style="height:400px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>


function sortNumber(a,b)    {
    return a - b;
}

function maxHeight() {
    var heights = new Array();
    $('#auto-height').each(function(){
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        heights.push($(this).height());
        heights = heights.sort(sortNumber).reverse();
        $(this).css('height', heights[0]);
    });        
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    maxHeight();
})

$(window).resize(maxHeight);


Try with this...
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question.  Also, doing something like `$('#auto-height').each(` never makes sense as id's should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Go through each parent div, get the total number of child divs and divide the parents height by them; like this:

```
<div class="parentDiv" style="height:500px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="parentDiv" style="height:200px;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

$('.parentDiv').each(function(index, record){
   var t = $(this).children().length;
   var h = ($(this).height() / t);
   $('div', this).css('height', h+'px');
});
```

This will go through each of the divs and update the child divs size based on the parents height.

Here's a fiddle to display it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/krEYR/1/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Using find here will also give any nested divs that may exist.  `children` should really be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below code would resize all children div of #yourdiv with equal height:

```
$("#yourdiv").each(function() {
    var ydh = $(this).height(),
        num = $(this).children("div").size(),
        dh  = ydh / num,
        ah  = 0;
    $(this).children("div").each(function(i) {
        var h;
        if (i + 1 == num) { // last item
            h = ydh - ah;
        } else {
            h = Math.round((i + 1) * dh);
        }
        $(this).height(h);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#yourdiv").each(` is not really valid as `id`s should be unique.  Perhaps a class instead?

Comment: Sure. I was trying to give an example, not a full solution.